# extract().to_dataframe() from a StanFit4Model does not work on pystan 2.18

Tags: python-3.x, pystan

I have estimated a model using `pystan`:

```
import pystan

stan_model = pystan.StanModel('stan_codes/stan_code_1.stan')
samples = stan_model.sampling(data = sdata, iter = 10, chains = 1, seed = 42)
model_results = {'mdata' : model_data, 'sdata': sdata, 'samples' : samples, 'model': stan_model}
```

Later I want to extract the "stuff" from the `samples` into a `dataframe` format. I am using

```
mdata, sdata, samples, model = [x for x in model_results.values()]
samples.extract().to_dataframe()
```

But I am getting an error:

```
 AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to_dataframe'
```

According to the [documentation](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) the `samples.extract()` should have an attribute `to_dataframe()`, right ? Am i doing something wrong here ? I am using `pystan version 2.18.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the extraction to DataFrame direct from the fit object

Something like ...

```
stan_model = pystan.StanModel('stan_codes/stan_code_1.stan')
samples = stan_model.sampling(data = sdata, iter = 10, chains = 1, seed = 42)
chains = samples.to_dataframe('parameter name')
```

Comment: Also, I would strongly urge you to use more than one chain. Four is the recommended number. They are needed for Rhat, the Gelman-Rubin convergence diagnostic.

Comment: Actually `samples.to_dataframe()` works (Takes all the parameters)